# Updating some parts of a Backbone Marionette ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm a new to Backbone.js and also to Backbone.Marionette and I'm having some troubles trying to follow the best patterns for my application.

I'm creating a mobile web application encapsulated by PhoneGap. I have a common layout (Facebook like): 2 sidebars, a main header and a content zone where all the views are loaded.

My initialization code for a Backbone.Marionette application is:

```
var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
    leftRegion: '#left-drawer',
    rightRegion: '#right-drawer',
    headerRegion: '#header',
    contentRegion: '#content',
    mainRegion: '#main'
});
```

This are my regions where the content will be attached. Later, just after initialize the router I have the next:

```
App.headerRegion.show(App.Views.Header);
App.leftRegion.show(App.Views.LeftSidebar);
App.rightRegion.show(App.Views.RightSidebar);
```

This will load my content to this new regions. The problem occurs in the HeaderView. The template for my Header view:

```
<button id="open-left"><img src="assets/img/icons/menu-icon.png"></button>
<h1 class="title logo"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" height="28px" width="167px"></h1>
<button id="open-right"><img src="assets/img/icons/chat-icon.png"></button>
```

The ItemView it's very simple too:

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: _.template(template),
});
```

In some parts of the app I don't want to use the `<img>` in the header. Some pages of the app will need to update this to a text, for example something like `<h1>Settings</h1>`. My question is, what's the best way to do it? Or better, what is the way to do it? Right now I don't know where to start and the only idea I've in mind is to create
a new ItemView with another template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marionette provides a useful function for this case, getTemplate, and you use this function isntead of the template : template declarations, like this.

```
SampleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
   getTemplate: function(){
      if (this.model.get("foo")) 
          return "#sample-template";
      else       
          return "#a-different-template";
   },
});
```

So in the parts of yur application where you need a diferent template wihtout image you just change modify a value on the view or your model that can be used in this function to made the change on the template at the time you call render.

Comment: so, if I dont get it wrong my ItemView should use a model. Then, attach it to the region. When I want to change the name, I should edit the model and the ItemView will be re-rendered and because it will use the `getTemplate` it will detect the changes. Is that right? Thank you!

Comment: using a model is optional, you can have just a new property of the view, chnge the value of the property acordingly to your scenarion and call render, once you call render, the getTemplate will be called, and it will check the value of the property, or you can do it with a model too. but the key is to use the getTemplate Function i think.